# Unable to pass object in custom keyboard extension from my main view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, custom-keyboard

Recently I was going through the implementation of scroll view in Custom Keyboard `iOS 8 Extension`. During implementation i have faced some adverse situations which are stated as below.

I have one main view controller and one custom keyboard extension. Here I have added one UITextField and two UIButtons `Choose color set 1 & Choose color set 2`. There are two sets of colors. I have a scroll view on the Custom Keyboard. If I scroll through the scroll view which added into the custom keyboard, a set of colors needs to displayed. Now my aim is to change the colors of the Custom Keyboard's scroll view against each of the buttons pressed in the main view controller.

Firstly, I have created an object of the Keyboard's view controller in the main view controller(App's view controller). I have set the arrays against each button click and assigned  each of the arrays using the objects of Keyboard's view controller. But the problem is when I checked the the array in Keyboard's view controller file, the assigned array is showing NULL value. 
          Secondly, I have tried the custom delegate approach but custom delegate is not working between the Extension and the Application.
          Thirdly, I have tried to use notification whether it is going to work. But it is also not possible through the notification.